# I deleted my Gitlab page, is it possible to republish it?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

I was experimenting with taking my Gitlab Pages page offline and deleted it in the process. Is it possible to republish it?

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger a build of your project and it will pubish your page again.